# wordpress generated css not being applied

Tags: html, wordpress, css, css-selectors

I have a problem with wordpress generated HTML - i don't know how to target it with css. I created a footer menu in footer.php:

```
<?php
/* main footer file */
?>

<footer>
    <div id="oblaci"></div>
    <div class="footer-nav">
    <div id="footer-logo">
    <a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/koprivko-
min.png"></a>
    </div>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( $arg = array(
            'menu_class'=> 'footer-nav',
            'theme_location' => 'footer'
        )); ?>
</div>
</footer>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and i'm trying to target ul(#menu-footer-nav) which is generated by wordpress element on the image below with css, and set the property:#menu-footer-nav{width:auto;
height:auto;
background:none}

It works on dev tools in chrome, but i cannot apply it.
[image]

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Wordpress is attaching an ID to the nav (as it has done), you can simply just target the id/class it supplies within your CSS. In this instance:

```
ul#menu-footer-nav {
    width:auto; 
    height:auto; 
    background:none;
}
```

Comment: I uploaded it and it doesn't work; tried multiple solutions: #menu-footer-nav ul{
    width:auto; 
    height:auto; 
    background:none;
} or .footer-nav #menu-footer-nav{} etc

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a selector that has higher *specifity*  than the selectors which are used by default. So, try this one:

```
footer div.menu-footer-nav-container > ul#menu-footer-nav.footer-nav { ... }
```

Be careful to write spaces and non-spaces exactly like this: It's the `ul` element having class `.footer-nav` *and* ID `#menu-footer-nav`, which is a direct child of the `div` with class `.menu-footer-nav-container`, which is inside (not necessarily a direct child)  the `footer` element.

This combines everything I can see in your screenshot. If it still doesn't apply, add `!important` to the single settings, but I think you shouldn't need that.

Comment: hmm - if the answer which you marked as accepted already worked, you shouldn't need `!important` at all... (since my solution contains that selector and combines it with more to achieve higher specifity)

Answer (score 0):

You're using wp_nav_menu() function, which will generate number of list items when fetching the specified menu. You can find more details in [wordpress site](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/).